# Get string from object

Tags: php, string, object

How do I get the email variable from this object in PHP?

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
```

Content of `$data`:

```
Object {email: "peter.m@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: `$data -> email`? been along time and no php interpreter here.

Comment: please provide us with the output of `print_r($data)`

Comment: That format in your second code snippet looks like Javascript, which tells us absolutely nothing about what's actually in `$data`.  Can you post the output of `var_dump($data)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's a json string? 
try:

```
$data = json_decode($data);
$email = $data->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work"

```
$email_string = $data->email;  //should work

//    or

$email_string = $data['email'];   //might also work
```

Comment: I tried this but I only get [ as output. This is why this seems strange to me.

Comment: Unless you converted `$_POST` to an object, it should be an array.  Use the second syntax.

Comment: can u print to us the plot of the following: var_dump ($data);$emails1=$data->email;$emails2=$data['email']; var_dump ($email1); var_dump ($emails2);